# What is the spec on the MIPI interface on PI Zero?

Tags: camera, raspicam, pi-zero

Noticed the latest Pi Zero has a MIPI connector now. Wondering if it supports 2-lane CSI or 4-lane CSI?

It's not specified anywhere I can find, only found a part reference to the connector being the same as compute kit which supports 4 lanes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi Zero and the Raspberry Pi A and B use a 2-lane CSI, whereas the compute module uses a 2-lane and a 4-lane CSI. [See here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=149610) and [here as well](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-designguide.md).